# Simplest way to reverse the order of strings in a make variable

Tags: makefile

Let's say you have a variable in a makefile fragment like the following:

```
MY_LIST=a b c d
```

How do I then reverse the order of that list?  I need:

```
$(warning MY_LIST=${MY_LIST})
```

to show

```
MY_LIST=d c b a
```

Edit:  the real problem is that

```
ld -r some_object.o ${MY_LIST}
```

produces an `a.out` with undefined symbols because the items in `MY_LIST` are actually archives, but in the wrong order.  If the order of `MY_LIST` is reversed, it will link correctly (I think).  If you know a smarter way to get the link order right, clue me in.

Comment: funny! I hope it's just for the warning :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A solution in pure GNU make:

> default: all
>
> foo = please reverse me
>
> reverse = $(if $(1),$(call
>   reverse,$(wordlist 2,$(words
>   $(1)),$(1)))) $(firstword $(1))
>
> all :     @echo $(call reverse,$(foo))

Gives:

> $ make
>
> me reverse please

Comment: Thanks! This one solved my exact problem, namely concatenating PDFs in order of the year in descending order. :)

Comment: `call reverse` not supported in GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 7):

An improvement to the GNU make solution:

> reverse = $(if $(wordlist 2,2,$(1)),$(call reverse,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(1)),$(1))) $(firstword $(1)),$(1))

- better stopping condition, original uses the empty string wasting a function call
- doesn't add a leading space to the reversed list, unlike the original

Answer (score 5):

Doh!  I could have just used a shell script-let:

`(for d in ${MY_LIST}; do echo $$d; done) | tac`

Comment: $ for d in one two three; do echo $d; done | tac
three
two
one

Superflous \n. But it's cool to learn about tac.

Answer (score 5):

You can also define search groups with ld:

```
ld -r foo.o -( a.a b.a c.a -)
```

Will iterate through a.a, b.a, and c.a until no new unresolved symbols can be satisfied by any object in the group.

If you're using gnu ld, you can also do:

```
ld -r -o foo.o --whole-archive bar.a
```

Which is slightly stronger, in that it will include every object from bar.a regardless of whether it satisfies an unresolved symbol from foo.o.

Answer (score 2):

Playing off of both [Ben Collins'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52722/309233) and [elmarco's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697/309233) answers, here's a punt to bash which handles whitespace "properly"<sup>1</sup>

```
reverse = $(shell printf "%s\n" $(strip $1) | tac)
```

which does the right thing, thanks to `$(shell)` automatically cleaning whitespace and `printf` automatically formatting each word in its arg list:

```
$(info [ $(call reverse,  one two   three four  ) ] )
```

yields:

```
[ four three two one ]
```

<sup>1</sup>...according to my limited test case (i.e., the `$(info ...)` line, above).

Comment: Didn't know printf when it has more argument than placeholder will loop until it consume. very smart way to create a loop. (Just dropped this comment because I didn't understand at first glance the trick)