# Ignoring file with similar names from compiling in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Suppose we have a directories two foo and bar. Where foo contains files example.S, run.c, exec.S and bar contains example.S
when I pass foo and bar as dependencies.
I want to compile only example.S in the directory bar by ignoring example.S in directory foo

**DEP := foo bar**

**DIR := $(foreach $dirs, $(DEP), $(shell $(HOME) -find -type d -name $(dirs)))**,

would provide me the absolute path of the foo and bar directories.

**FILES := $(foreach file, $(DIR), $(wildcard $(file)/*))**, would provide me the list of files foo and bar as

foo/example.S foo/run.c foo/exec.S bar/example.S

I would like to check for multiple occurance of file with same name. and only compile the latest, i.e, instead of foo/example.S I like to compile bar/example.S...

I have no idea how to do it, As I am very new to creation of Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more of a shell question than a makefile one.   What you want to do is create a shell command that generates two column list for each file -- the first column being the full filename, and the second being just the filename.  Then sort it, and remove the ones with duplicate filenames, and then output only the first column.

Basically you would use:

```
DIRS = ./A ./B
files=`find $(DIRS) -type f -exec sh -c 'echo {} $$(basename {})' \; | sort -u --stable -k2,2 | awk '{print $$1}'`
```

You would have to replace the `./B ./A` with a sorted list of directories you wanted to search in.   Notice the `$$`'s -- Make resolves these to `$` before running the shell command.   The `$(DIRS)` only has a single `$`, so it is expanded before the command is executed.

Explanation:

`find ./B ./A -type f -exec sh -c 'echo {} $(basename {})' \;` : This searches the directories `B` and then `A` (in that order)

`type -f` specifies files only -- it won't return directories.

`-exec sh -c 'echo {} $(basename {})' \;` : for each file found, it will run the echo command where `{}` resolves to the file it found.  It will therefore print the full file path, followed by just the filename.

`sort -u --stable -k2,2`:  Sort the list of files based on column 2 (the filename).  The `-u` means unique, so if there are matching files, it only prints the first.    The `--stable` means that if there are two matching lines, it will always output the first one.

`awk '{print $1}'`: print the first column of the output (the full path name).

You then have a list of unique filenames, including their directories in `$(files)`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, when I "echo $(files)" I do get list of files.. But,

Comment: Thanks for the solution, when I "echo $(files)" I do get list of files.. But, OBJ_SRC := $(info $(files)) gives the following
`find /../../foo/example.S /../../foo/run.c /../../foo/exec.S /.S /../../bar/example.S -type f -exec sh -c 'echo {} $(basename {})' \; | sort -u --stable -k2,2 | awk '{print $1}'` But, I need only the file names with this command.

Answer (score 0):

There's a (relatively) simple way to get what you want, starting with [reversing a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674/simplest-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-strings-in-a-make-variable) (with thanks to @simona). After you have calculated `DIR` your way,

```
reverse = $(if $(1),$(call reverse,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(1)),$(1)))) $(firstword $(1))

DIR := $(call reverse,$(DIR))
```

Then use [VPATH](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search):

```
VPATH = $(DIR)
```

Now you can tell Make to search for a file (such as `example.S`), and it will find the last instance (in this case `.../bar/example.S`):

```
example: example.S
    @echo building $@ from $^
```