# Makefile merge similar rules into generic one

Tags: makefile

I have the following pattern in Makefile:

```
%_a0_b0.o: %.c
    $(CMD) a0 b0 -i $^ -o $@

%_a1_b0.o: %.c
    $(CMD) a1 b0 -i $^ -o $@

%_a0_b1.o: %.c
    $(CMD) a0 b1 -i $^ -o $@

%_a1_b1.o: %.c
    $(CMD) a1 b1 -i $^ -o $@
```

As I will increase the number of possibles combinaisons `ai bj` I would like to be able to merge all thoses rules in one.

I was able to use the same command on each recipes thanks to some text manipulation functions and the reverse function described here: [Simplest way to reverse the order of strings in a make variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674/simplest-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-strings-in-a-make-variable).

```
reverse = $(if $(wordlist 2,2,$(1)),$(call reverse,$(wordlist 2,$(words $(1)),$(1))) $(firstword $(1)),$(1))

A=$(word 2, $(call reverse,$(subst _, , $(notdir $@))))
B=$(word 1, $(call reverse,$(subst _, , $(notdir $@))))

%_a0_b0.o: %.c
    $(CMD) $(A) $(B) -i $^ -o $@

%_a1_b0.o: %.c
    $(CMD) $(A) $(B) -i $^ -o $@

%_a0_b1.o: %.c
    $(CMD) $(A) $(B) -i $^ -o $@

%_a1_b1.o: %.c
    $(CMD) $(A) $(B) -i $^ -o $@
```

But I'm stuck with the `target: prerequisite` part, Is there a way to merge thoses four rules to something more generic ?

Comment: Are you sure that `notdir` is the right choice? After your `subst` the last element of these lists will be `b1.o` in contrast to the `a0` `a1` etc.

Comment: You're right, I should have used `basename` instead of `notdir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GNU make you can use a combination of `foreach`, `eval` and `call` to instantiate make rules in a loop nest:

```
A := a0 a1
B := b0 b1

define MY_rule
%_$(1)_$(2).o: %.c
    $$(CMD) $(1) $(2) -i $$^ -o $$@
endef
$(foreach a,$(A),$(foreach b,$(B),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(a),$(b)))))
```

Note: the `$$` in the macro definition are not typos, they are needed because this macro is expanded twice. Have a look at the [this part of the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) for the details.